# GetVideosAsync does not bring private videos - C#

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm using the vimeo-dot-net library and making a request through the 
**GetVideosAsync()** method that returns me the videos of a certain user.

However, it only brings public videos. How to bring all private videos from a user to vimeo?

Comment: Are you supposed to be able to view this user's private videos? If not, I wouldn't expect the API to return them

Comment: Are you using an authenticated or unauthenticated (client_credentials) token? If you're using an authenticated token, what scopes are applied to it? https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#understanding-the-auth-process

Comment: consegui resolver, estava utilizando um token não autenticado. Obrigado pela ajuda